# I have a question about logstash grok filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, elk

I want to extract fields through logstash's grok filter.
For example, if the following log occurs, I would like to extract the message time, thread, log level, and status code.

2020-01-01 10:10:10 [QuartzScheduler-1] ERROR c.l.c.i.c.t.a.c.AmazonElbV2Task-Exception occurred ..... LoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: Throttling;

Message time, thread, and log levels were extracted through the following filters. How do I extract the status code?

%{TIME:messageTime} [(?[A-Za-z0-9\W.-_]+)] %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following GROK expression. it was tested using GROK debugger with your provided input. I suggest you also use GROK debugger from kibana or you can find 1 online in order to build your GROK expressions.

```
^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:event_timestamp}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:thread}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}%{GREEDYDATA}Status Code: %{NUMBER:status:int}%{GREEDYDATA}$
```